# What is the function of listAction()?

Tags: typo3, content-management-system, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I am having trouble getting my extension to run on TYPO3 v9.5.11. When i try running it, it gives me an error saying "no Template found in listAction()".

What is listAction supposed to do and how do I implement it?
I have already checked multiple Tutorials and Manuals but could not find an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listAction is the default action. It expects a 'Resources/Private/Templates/List.html' template file. Provide it then the message will disappear.

Please have a look at your extensions 'ext_localconf.php'. In there you can configure your plugins and thus define the default actions.

Please refer to the documentation:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/

Answer (score 1):

That might mean that an extbase plugin tries to render a template for the listAction(). Normally, that would be called List.html.

Anyways, I do not find your exact error in the core so it might be generated by your extension? I would search through all the files for "no Template found" to see where it is coming from.